# add class to body if any of the pages have a certain class with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I add a class to the body if certain page have `div` has some particular class?

When switching through the different pages I want to find a certain class and if that class exist I want to add another class to the body.

How do find a certain class when switching over the pages?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this from React would be like this:

```
const HelloReact = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const classExists = document.querySelector('.target-class') !== null;
    if (!classExists) return
    document.body.classList.add('body-class')
  }, []);
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="target-class">Hello Target</div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default HelloReact;
```

This could be either a util function you could import in a component or transform it into a hook that could be used on various components / pages.